# How to remove choppiness from streaming?

Tags: camera, pi-4, streaming-video, motion

I tried `GStreamer` but it was not getting installed as its dependency repo link which we place in source.list was outdated. I tried `mjpg-stream` but it kept saying that I don't have a camera connected and its module installed. So I switched to `motion` and it is working but is choppy.

I am using an [i-ball ROBOK20](https://www.iball.co.in/Product/Desktop-Accessories/Web-Cameras-/Robo-K20/833) web camera to do live streaming using `motion` in Raspberry PI 4 4GB RAM variant.

I have followed [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-Raspberry-Pi-Webcam-Server-and-Stream-/) instruction to create a streaming server. But the live feed is choppy. How can I stream without any choppiness?

Comment: Please add your motion configuration file `/etc/motion/motion.conf` to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the choppiness by changing the stream_maxrate from 1 to 30 and disabling not needing things.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: Yes, you can increase the number up to "100" but if you configured this for internet connection, the fewer number is better.